# angular nested *ngFor in template used multiple | keyvalue --> get first "value" of key

Tags: angular

My code:

```
<div *ngFor="let measurement of measurementsDict | keyvalue" class="scrolling-container block-2" id="channel_bar">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let signal of measurement.value | keyvalue">
        {{signal.key}}
        <ng-container *ngFor=" let channel of signal.value | keyvalue">
            <ng-container *ngIf="(channel.key == 'true')">
                {{signal.key}}
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

The first `{{signal.key}}` is different than the second `{{signal.key}}`.
Because of using `| keyvalue` twice.

How can i get the first `{{signal.key}}` on the second place (in the code)?
As far as i know you cannot change `| keyvalue` for iterating over an object

Comment: can you share the object your are trying to iterate over ? i.e. signal or measurement.value

Comment: measurementsDict is a dict:

{measurement1: {signal: {active: "true"}}}

i need "signal" if active=="true"

Comment: shouldn't the second signal.key be channel.key then??

Comment: I dont want to display the value of "channel.key".
if "channel.key" is true, i want to display the value of "signal.key" that i got in the first place when i call "signal.key"

Comment: @B.Obama This is exactly what you are doing!

Comment: @Thriller
nope.
i have to use | keyvalue when iterating.
so the "key" in the second call of {{signal.key}} is different then the first call of {{signal.key}}

Comment: You may want to compare `channel.value` instead of `channel.key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake:

had to change to -->`channel.value == true`

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div *ngFor="let measurement of measurementsDict | keyvalue" class="scrolling-container block-2"
                        id="channel_bar">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let signal of measurement.value | keyvalue">
                            <ng-container *ngFor=" let channel of signal.value | keyvalue">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="(channel.key === 'active')">

                                    <ng-container *ngIf="(channel.value == true)">
                                            {{signal.key}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>
```